# ColdFusion to JSP conversion

Tags: java, jsp, coldfusion, application.cfc

I am a ColdFusion developer moving to Java.  I thought it would be useful to learn Java from the perspective of ColdFusion by converting a ColdFusion application to JSP.  The part I am stuck on is how to convert the logic in the Application.cfc file to a JSP environment.  For instance the onRequest code that directs the application when moving about the application.  Is there a good relevant tutorial to help me?

For Java developers unfamiliar with ColdFusion the Application.cfc is read every time there is a request by a user. In this file is the onRequest method that can be used to identify conditions that exist in order to direct the application.  For instance, checking if the user is logged in and if not directing them to the log in page. Is there a best practice for establishing this kind of condition checking in a java application?

Comment: You probably need an answer from a Java dev - in which case you should include a bit of info about what application.cfc and onrequest() actually do - how they function. I suspect a Java dev will recommend a framework that provides these functions or similar ones.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will edit the question to include some of that information.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a *servlet filter*.

Comment: I will review servlets and see if they provide the solution.

Comment: Global vars etc can be put in the `ServletContext`. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091377/using-application-scope-variables-in-java

Comment: A servlet filter is not a servlet. Its a filter that intercepts the request before it gets to a servlet. And a servlet is basically a page. Even a jsp becomes a servlet in the backend.

Comment: Another thing: do you intend to use a Java web application framework? Like Spring MVC, Struts or Stripes - which I used myself once for re-writing an existing CF application. They feature interceptor classes that can easily be configured to run at several stages in the request/response cycle, for instance to make sure a user is logged in or certain shared data is available / actions are performed.

Comment: As I have just started working with Java I am trying to determine what is considered best practice. I have not looked into a framework as of yet due to the difference in opinion I have run across in the past with what is the best framework.

Comment: Thank you developerwjk for the clarification on servlets and filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of developerwjk using either a servlet or a filter with a urlPattern of "/*" can serve as an alternative to the ColdFusion application cfc onRequest method.