# Combining output of two java servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I'm making a hostel management system with backend in java. I made a header class that shows the menu and I want it to be included on every servlet of my project. I have tried using request dispatcher. like this:

```
RequestDispatcher rd1 = req.getRequestDispatcher("/header");
    rd1.include(req, res);
```

When I put it on some servlet, the output of that servlet is removed(only that output which is placed after this include line) and only header servlet is displayed. I have overloaded both `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods in header servlet.

[The Following picture shows that my header is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0vY.png)

An Example servlet is here in which I'm including header servlet.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class add extends HttpServlet{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
throws IOException,ServletException
{
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    res.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<html><head><title>Add student</title></head>");
    RequestDispatcher rd1 = req.getRequestDispatcher("/header");   
    rd1.include(req, res);           //I want to show the data after this line as well
    out.println("<form method='post' action='addtoDatabase'>");
    out.println("Roll Number : <input type='text' name='roll' placeholder='student Roll Number'><br>");
    out.println("Name : <input type='text' name='studentName' autofocus placeholder='student name'><br>");
    out.println("room number : <input type='text' name='roomNumber' placeholder='Room Number'><br>");
    out.println("Address : <input type='text' name='address' placeholder='Address'><br>");
    out.println("Phone : <input type='text' name='phone' placeholder='03001234567'><br>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='Add Student'> ");

    out.println("</form></body></html>");
    out.close();
}
}
```

In the above code, the HTML form is not been displayed on the browser. Only the header is displayed as I have shown in the following screenshot.

[Screenshot of remove page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho6jx.png)

How can I combine the output of both header and any other servlets on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are `Session Scope`, also have `Application Scope`. I am wondering what are you achieving is share some data between different sessions. That is you need `Application Scope`. That is [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) , Please refer to [Using application scope variables in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091377/using-application-scope-variables-in-java)

Comment: hey, @Qinfdei I have checked the links you provided me. I was about to try addServlet() function but then I only removed the close statement from header servlet. Everything Worked fine for me then.